# Does the Lumia 900 have a compass?

Tags: lumia-900

The [Wikipedia article for the Lumia 900](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nokia_Lumia_900) lists 'digital compass' among the features of the phone. Likewise the [Lumia 900 spec sheet](http://www.nokia.com/gb-en/products/phone/lumia900/specifications/) on Nokia's website lists 'Compass (Magnetometer Sensor)' as a feature.

Therefore the answer to my question would seem to be "yes", *but* when I install certain apps from the marketplace (such as the new PhotoSynth app), I get a compatibility warning:

> Some features in this app might not work because your phone does not have: compass

So which is it? Does this phone have a compass or not? Or maybe there's more than one right answer?

Comment: What other apps other than PhotoSynth give this warning? Have you tried installing the CompassVO app? See if that works. Maybe the apps are erroneously reporting the missing compass. From the links you've shown, the lumia 900 has to have the compass.

Comment: Same warning for that app and one other. This is very curious.

Comment: Very strange indeed, is your phone's firmware up-to-date?

Comment: Yes, I'm fairly certain it is. The version information on my phone exactly matches (in all details) what is reported here http://www.wpcentral.com/nokia-lumia-900-update-now-live

Comment: The Zune client reports my phone is up to date.

Comment: I asked a friend of mine who also has a Lumia 900 to take a look at this. His unit seems not to have this problem. Obviously this suggests that my unit is simply defective. Once I've confirmed to my own satisfaction that this is indeed the case, I'll delete this question.

Comment: Don't delete. Maybe someone else with another defective Lumia 900 may find their answer here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the AT&T rep I spoke with, this is a known issue with the phone. I was told that it could be fixed by backing up and performing a hard reset of the phone. I did so and it did appear to fix the problem.

To be clear, I reset the phone via:

1. Settings app.
2. about (system page).
3. 'reset your phone' button.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Nokia](http://www.nokia.com/gb-en/products/phone/lumia900/specifications/) it has a compass.